# jQuery Mobile and Normal jQuery dialogs conflicting/not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, dialog

i have a series of dialogs that are called up when a form on a site is submitted. I have since adapted the site for mobile use and incorporated jquery movile (1.4.2) to the standard jquery and jquery-ui.

My problem is, on the mobile site where and when all three scripts are loaded, the dialogs that the form shows does not work with the jquery mobile script loaded in.

Below is the code of my site; normal jquery (1.11.0) , jquery mobile (1.4.2) and jquery ui (1.10.4) not show due to size but are linked in the main html page.

**Main HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/jquery_mobile.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="CSS/Dropdown.css">
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Dropdown_ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
.contact_form_message


{
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 330px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 82px !important;

    background-color: #F4FAD8;
    color: #2D4206;
    margin-top: 5px;
    outline: none;  
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #A9AC95;
    position: absolute;

}



#form_mail_logo
{
width: 50px;    
height: 50px;
position:relative;
border: none;
top: -61px;
right: -435px;
}

.contact_form_fieldset
{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
height: 355px;
}

.Form .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
float: right;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-right: 8px;
background-color: #A9AC95;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #2D4206;
color: #2D4206;
font-size: 16px;
outline: none;
}

</style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>


.Form .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
float: right;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-right: 8px;
background-color: #A9AC95;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #2D4206;
color: #2D4206;
font-size: 16px;
outline: none;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<meta name="description" content="Tree Pro Ltd">
<meta name="keywords" content="Tree Surgery, TreePro, Tree Pro, Tree Care">
<meta name="author" content="Tree Pro Ltd">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.333">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>
Contact us
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery_ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="JS/dropdownhover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/cookie_accepted.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/mobile_detect.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="bodyid">
<div title="Cookie Policy" class="Cookie_Warning" >
<p>Wellcome to Tree Pro Ltd. By using this site, you agree to that cookies will be stored on your computer.</p>
Read more about our cookie policy <a href="privacy.html">here</a>.

</div>

<div class="container">
<p>
<div class="topheader"><img src="Images/general/logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo"><span id="sitetitle">Tree Pro Ltd</span><span id="telnumber">Tel: 01622 851576</span>
<a href="http://facebook.treeproltd.co.uk"><img id="facebook_logo" src="Images/icons/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook icon"></a><a href="http://twitter.treeproltd.co.uk"> <img id="twitter_logo" src="Images/icons/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter icon"></a><a href="mailto:contact@treeproltd.co.uk?Subject=Enquiry"> <img id="mail_logo" src="Images/icons/Mail.png" alt="Mail icon"></a></div>
<p>
<div class="bottomheader">

<ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="left"><a href="/">Home</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li><a>Our Services</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li class="top"><a href="felling.html">Tree Surgery - Felling</a></li>
                     <li><a href="pruning.html">Tree Surgery - Pruning</a></li>
                     <li class="bottom"><a href="patiocleaning.html">Patio Cleaning</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                </ul>
            </li>


            <li ><a>Our Work</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li class="top"><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                     <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                     <li><a href="ourpartners.html">Our Partners</a></li>

                      <li class="bottom"><a href="faqs.html">FAQ's</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="right"><a>Contact</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li class="top"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us </a></li>
                     <li class="bottom"><a href="findus.html">Find Us</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>

    <form id="searchform" name="search" action="searchresults.php" method="get" >
    <input id="searchbox" type="text"  name="query" value=""  >
    <input id="searchbutton" value="Search"  onClick="Clear();" type="submit" >
    <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="mobile_bottomheader"> 

<select class="mobile_dropdown" id="mobile_select">
    <option class="mobile_dropdown_option" value="contactus.html">Contact us</option>
    <option value="/">Home</option>
    <option value="felling.html">Tree Felling</option>
    <option value="pruning.html">Tree Pruning</option>
    <option value="patiocleaning.html">Patio Cleaning</option>
    <option value="gallery.html">Gallery</option>
    <option value="aboutus.html">About us</option>
    <option value="testimonials.html">Testimonials</option>
    <option value="ourpartners.html">Our Partners</option>
    <option value="faqs.html">FAQ's</option>

    <option value="findus.html">Find us</option>
</select>



</div>
<p>

<div class="maincontent">
  <div class="form_content_title">Contact Us</div>
  <br><br>
 <div class="form_text_content"> 
  We thank you for taking interest in Tree Pro and appreciate you want to contact us. <br><br>
  Please use the contact form below to directly contact us or alternatively email us by clicking the mail icon on the form.
  <br><br>  To find out where we are, either click <a href="findus.html">here</a> or select the "Find Us" option from the contact menu.

 </div>
 <img src="Images/general/woodland_1.jpg" alt="Woodland Image" id="static_form_image">
 <br><br>
 <form data-role="none" class="contact_form"  name="contact_form">
 <fieldset class="contact_form_fieldset">
 <label class="contact_form_label">Name:</label>     <input id="name" class="contact_form_input" name="name" type="text"><br><br>
 <label class="contact_form_label">E-mail:</label>    <input id="email" class="contact_form_input" name="email" type="text"><br><br>
 <label class="contact_form_label">Phone:</label>    <input id="phone" class="contact_form_input" name="phone" type="text"><br><br>
 <label class="contact_form_label">Subject:</label>
 <select data-role="none" class="contact_form_input_subject" id="subject" name="subject">
 <option data-role="none" value="Tree Surgery">Tree Surgery</option>
 <option data-role="none" value="Patio Cleaning">Patio Cleaning</option>
 <option data-role="none" value="Fire Wood / Wood Chippings">Fire wood / Wood chippings</option> 
 <option data-role="none" value="Testimonial">Testimonial</option>
 <option data-role="none" value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
 <option data-role="none" value="Other">Other</option>
 </select>
 <br><br>
 <label class="contact_form_label">Message:</label> <textarea class="contact_form_message" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
 <br><br>
 <input class="contact_form_button" name="submit" data-role="none" type="submit" onclick="Form_Validation()" value="submit">
 </fieldset>
 </form>

 <a href="mailto:contact@treeproltd.co.uk?Subject=Enquiry"> <img id="form_mail_logo" src="Images/icons/Mail.png" alt="Mail icon"></a>

<div id="success_message" title="Thankyou" class="hidden_message" >
<p>Thank you for contacting us, we shall be in touch shortley.</p>
</div>
<div  id="no_name_message" title="No Name entered" class="hidden_message">
  <p >No name has been entered, please enter a name.</p>
</div>
<div id="invalid_email_message" title="Invalid E-mail address" class="hidden_message">
  <p>The email address you have entered is invalid, please enter a valid one.</p>
</div>
<div id="invalid_phone_message" title="Invalid phone number" class="hidden_message">
  <p>The phone number you have entered is invalid, please enter a valid one consisting of 11 digits.</p>
</div>
<div id="invalid_phone_and_email_message" title="Invalid contact details" class="hidden_message">
  <p>Both the phone number and the email address you have entered are not valid, please ensure they are both correct.</p>
</div>
 </div>
<p class="maincontentspace"></p>
<br><br>
<div class="footer">
<p>

<div id="footer_links"><a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="help.html">Help</a></div>
<div id="copyright">© Copyright Tree Pro Ltd 2014 </div></div>
<p class="footerspace"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**mobile_detect.js** (determines if jquery mobile is to be loaded by screen width and if so also displays the ID element "mobile_select" what is the mobile navigation menu for the site.)

```
$(function(){

 if (screen.width < 600)
 {





var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = '/JS/jquery_mobile.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);



 document.getElementById("mobile_select").onchange = function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
            window.location.href = this.value;
        }        
    };
 }

 });
```

**main.js** (displays dialogs from hidden divs when conditions are met during form submission)

```
// Initation when submit button is clicked
$(function() {
  $(".contact_form_button").click(function() {

//Getting ID's from html
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var subject = $("select#subject").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();


//Triming of white space for email adresses and phone numbers


var trimed_email = $.trim($("#email").val());

var trimed_phone = $.trim($("#phone").val());

//Getting posistion of email elemnts
var x=document.getElementById("email").value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

//Validation below          

if (document.getElementById("name").value == "")

{
$("#no_name_message").dialog({dialogClass: "Form"});

return false;

}

else if (((atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) && (trimed_email.length>=1)) && (trimed_phone.length!==11 && trimed_phone.length!==0))

{
$("#invalid_phone_and_email_message").dialog({dialogClass: "Form"});
return false;
            }
else  if  (trimed_phone.length!==11 && trimed_phone.length!==0 )
{

$("#invalid_phone_message").dialog({dialogClass: "Form"});
return false;
}
else if ((atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) && (trimed_email.length>=1))

{

$("#invalid_email_message").dialog({dialogClass: "Form"});
return false;

}   

else    
    {
//Form proceesing below   
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;

//alert (dataString);return false;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/form.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: $("#success_message").dialog({dialogClass: "Form"}),

});
return false;
    }

  });

});
```

So, any ideas why the divs with the classes of "hidden_message" are not showing up when jquery mobile is loaded?

Any help much appreciated, Elliott.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the end. Had to tweak one of the java-script files as was preventing the JS code for the dialog s from loading.